# Write a function that returns a vector of ggplot2 graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this project where I want to make the same plots for a variety of different data frames. I was thinking I could do this by writing a function that takes a data frame as an input and then returns a vector of plots---something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100))
plot.list <- function(df){
  g1 <- qplot(x, y, data = df)
  g2 <- qplot(x, x + y, data = df)
  c(g1, g2) 
}
```

And I'd like to do this:

```
print(plot.list(df)[1])
```

getting the same results as if I had done:

```
print(qplot(x,y, data = df))
```

As you'll see, this doesn't work---it seems to print out the data frame that the plot is based on (?). My guess is that I'm misunderstanding something pretty basic about how objects work in R or the nature of ggplot2 plots. Thanks for any advice (or perhaps recommendations on better ways to do what I'm trying to do).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways you could approach this sort of thing, but one trick you may not be aware of is that `ggplot2` has a special operator for this sort of purpose, i.e. creating the same graph using different data frames:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10))
d2 <- data.frame(x=20:29,y=runif(10))
p <- ggplot(data = d1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
print(p)
print(p %+% d2)
```

So the `%+%` operator will plug in the data frame `d2` into the plot structure defined by `p`. That way you can create the plot once and then apply it to different data frames.

To more directly address the use you outline in your question, once you create the first plot, `p`, you can `lapply` this plot structure along a list of data frames:

```
d3 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rexp(10))
rs <- lapply(list(d1,d2,d3),FUN = function(x,p){p %+% x},p=p)
```

And then you have three plots stored in `rs`.

Comment: Nice. Can we do this with different variables?

Comment: @MYaseen208 I don't believe so. This will assume that the data frames have the same structure (i.e. same variables, with the same names) but potentially different values.

Comment: How would I go about, if I had 2 different geoms with different dataframes in my plot?

Comment: @TobiO If I'm understanding you, I don't think this method would apply in that case. If you're making fundamentally different plots with different layers, you can't reuse the same ggplot() call on multiple data frames, let alone different data frames.

Comment: Thanks! It's actually the same plot using one aggregated dataframe for errorbars and means etc and one with the whole dataset (to show the actual underlying data)

Answer (score 9):

Store the objects in a `list` instead of a vector:

```
plot.list <- function(df){
  g1 <- qplot(x, y, data = df)
  g2 <- qplot(x, x + y, data = df)
  list(g1, g2) 
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference.  But it obviously does.  I guess I should define a `c` method for ggplot objects.

Comment: @Hadley - It didn't really make much sense to me either, but I tested it and seemed to work so I rolled with it.

Comment: `c.ggplot = function(...) list(...)` ? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way to generate multiple plots from different data frames sharing the same column names.

```
d1 = data.frame(x = 1:10,  y = rexp(10))
d2 = data.frame(x = 5:20,  y = rnorm(16))
d3 = data.frame(x = 21:30, y = rpois(10, 4))

plots = llply(list(d1, d2, d3), `%+%`, p = qplot(x, y))
```